# How can I stop civicrm_metatag_metatags_view_alter() altering non-CiviCRM URLs

Tags: drupal

The purpose of function civicrm_metatag_metatags_view_alter() is to ensure the metatag URLs include the query parameters. The problem is that it acts on non-CiviCRM pages.

'Metatag' is a Drupal module for adding  tags to the rendered HTML, and this function is in drupal/civicrm.module.

**Proposed solution**

civicrm_metatag_metatags_view_alter() should be modified to only work on CiviCRM pages. With all kudos going to @Chris-Burgess I've created an issue CRM-17594 and PR https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/pull/328 to resolve this.

**My question: How do I check that a URL is a CiviCRM URL?**

As discussed below, the answer is to check if arg(0) equals 'civicrm'.

**Description of problem**

I get the following PHP Notice ...

> Notice: Array to string conversion in _civicrm_get_url_parameters_as_url_string() (line 295 of .../sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module).

A page where this occurs is http://citybibleforum.org/library?&title=&field_speakers_tid=&field_topics_tid=&field_bible_reference_value=&field_episode_date_value%5Bmin%5D=2011-08-12&field_episode_date_value%5Bmax%5D=2012-08-12&field_is_audio_value=All&field_is_text_value=All&field_is_video_value=All&page=46

The parameters causing the notice are ...

> field_episode_date_value[min]=2011-08-12&field_episode_date_value[max]=2012-08-12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend a check to test that the Drupal path (eg [`current_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/current_path/7)) commences with `civicrm`. This is untested, but I think you want something like the following -

```
/**
 * Alter metatags before being cached.
 *
 * This hook is invoked prior to the meta tags for a given page are cached.
 *
 * @param array $output
 *   Metatags to be displayed.
 * @param string $instance
 *  Context.
 */
function civicrm_metatag_metatags_view_alter(&$output, $instance) {
  if (arg(0) == 'civicrm') {
    $linkUrls = array('og:url', 'canonical', 'shortlink');
    foreach ($linkUrls as $url) {
      if (isset($output[$url]['#attached']['drupal_add_html_head'][0][0]['#value'])) {
        $output[$url]['#attached']['drupal_add_html_head'][0][0]['#value'] .= _civicrm_get_url_parameters_as_url_string();
      }
    }  
  }
}
```

- [`hook_metatag_metatags_view_alter()`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/metatag/tree/metatag.api.php#n215)
- [`civicrm_metatag_metatags_view_alter()`](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-drupal/blob/7.x-master/civicrm.module#L263)

I don't really like the look of the fixed `[0][0]` in that code either?

If you're submitting a fix, you should check out [CRM-16495: Metatag canonicals are broken, q is multiplied](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16495) which looks like it fixes the error message you're experiencing also. That fix is committed to 4.7 now.

I think your proposed solution is correct, CiviCRM shouldn't be messing with metatags if it hasn't been involved in the page generation.

Comment: Thanks Chris! That's what I expected, but I vaguely remembered coming across a case where it's possible to change the relative path civicrm uses. Is that possible, or am I mis-remembering?

Comment: Relocating CiviCRM can probably be done eg with rewrites at the webserver level, but IMO Drupal would have `civicrm` at the start of both [`request_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/request_path/7) and [`current_path()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21path.inc/function/current_path/7). Doing it another way (`hook_menu_alter()`?) would probably cause bigger issues than just with metatags - I'd be interested to know how else it can be done, but that's definitely another question :D

Comment: Thanks again, Chris! I'll apply the patch to CRM-16495. Another question: in civicrm.module there are other tests checking if this is a CiviCRM page (I should have found these earlier!). For instance, the function civicrm_on_user_page() tests isset($_POST['_qf_default']) and other functions use tests of the form arg(0) == 'civicrm'. Rather than introduce a new test using stristr(), would we be able to reuse one of those tests?

Comment: If I've answered your question right, please mark the answer accordingly? Note that the patch to CRM-16495 doesn't solve your question, I think it just addresses the warning you mentioned.

Comment: `arg(0) == 'civicrm'` is a better way of detecting whether we're in CiviCRM than the one I proposed, yes. `isset($_POST['_qf_default'])` tests whether an HTML_QuickForm post is being made.

Comment: Updated suggested method to use `arg(0)` instead, thanks @KenWest!

Comment: Cheers, Chris. Thanks for your answer (which I hope I marked appropriately)